# Firebase database write operation freezes the app while writing 100s of data at same time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need write 100s of records to the Firebase database when the user opens the app for the first time, but the Firebase write operation freezes the app totally while doing that.

Following is the method which produces the problem, I am running this method in a fragment, switching between the fragments while running this method in the other just freezes the app

```
    private void getContactsAndWrite() {
Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
while (phones.moveToNext()) {
  String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
  String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
  String key = FirebaseUtil.getContactsRef().push().getKey();
  Map<String, Object> contact = new HashMap<>();
  contact.put("name", name);
  contact.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
  FirebaseUtil.getContactsRef().child(key).setValue(contact);
}
phones.close();
```

}

App doesn't freeze when this method is commented

```
FirebaseUtil.getContactsRef().child(key).setValue(contact);
```

The same freezing issues also shows while fast scrolling through these contacts displayed in a RecyclerView, in its adapter I have the code to write the contact info to the firebase database if it is not found in firebase database

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The Firebase Database client performs all interaction with the server on a background thread, so it should not freeze the UI. But without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it is quite useful) it will be hard to say more.

Comment: When I debugged the app I found dataRef.setValue() and dataRef.updateChildren() method causing all the problem. Calling 100s of these at same time freezing the app

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , you are saying all interactions with server is on a background thread, but when I commented the code dataRef.setValue() there is no issue for my app it just works fine

Comment: I have no doubt the code you have triggers the behavior you describe. But the code you shared is not enough for me to reproduce the problem with. For example: writing a tight loop with hundreds of calls like that is likely to lead to memory outages/garbage collection delays. Without seeing the code you have that reproduces the problem, we can't see what is happening and we end up with your speculation ("it is Firebase") versus mine ("it is somehow trigger by how you call the Firebase APIs").

Comment: That's why I asked you to provide a so-called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Part of this is that you try to isolate the problem by starting in a new app. In many cases this leads to developers finding a problem in their own code, or a workaround for their problem. If it doesn't do so for you, having the MCVE is a perfect starting point for others to reproduce your problem on our systems and investigate.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I updated the question with the method which causing the problem, Can you please run that code in your system and check

Comment: @m.ka did you find a solution for this.
I have the same problem.